# User login with Oauth

Tags: meteor, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts

I am a new to the Oauth facing a problem creating meteor app. I am using Accounts-password package to handle the user log in. My system doesn't provide registration and use third party to authenticate the user after I get the access token I don't know how to log the user in, since I don't have a username or password.

In a normal senario I belive it is going to be something like

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(<email>, <password>);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have a remote authentication service that you are using? Does it comply with the OAuth standard? How does the remote system work?

Comment: yes, it is following the standards. it returns an authorization code which I exchange to access token. I use the access token to prefore the REST requests.

Comment: Ok, so you are able to login using oauth, but you need to tell Meteor that the user is logged in?

Comment: that's completely ture

Comment: Why don't you use the built in Meteor.loginWith[Facebook/Twitter/Google] ? Do you know they exist and decided they don't fit / are trying with another service or did I not understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MathieuK. Acutually I am using my Oauth server. so It's not google, facebook or twitter

Comment: ok so why do you want to login with password then?

Comment: I am not. I am just giving example how it would be if it's login with password. so It would be esier to understand .